# Does analysis at two points in time count as 'longitudinal'?

Tags: reference-request, time-series

According to whatever norms and expectations exist in the econometrics literature - if an analysis looks at two points in time can this be described as longitudinal, or would more time slices generally be expected for work that describes itself as such?

Comment: If the two points look at different samples then in my view it may be a stretch to call it longitudinal

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  A longitudinal study involves repeated observations of the same variables (e.g., people) over short or long periods of time.   You can have more than two points in time for your project.  It really depends on your study's converge (time periods under analysis).

Comment: Modified question: what if we do a single regression to look at change in Y between two points in time, based on both X and change in X? still longitudinal?